# Loading Python Module in C++ from relative path

Tags: python, c++

I have C++ program written at my home directory(/home/sunil/test.cc)

My Python module is residing at following path :- (/projects/name/dir/subdir/test.py)

I am trying to import python module in C++ using following Python-C API `PyImport_ImportModule` function.

```
PyImport_ImportModule(/projects/name/dir/subdir/test.py)
```

I am giving full path as argument to the function as shown above but it doesn't give any compilation error but when i try to print any variable value from python module it gives segmentation fault issue.

Couple of questions here :-

1. If it is not able to load the python module then how it is not giving any compilation error?
2. How do i provide the python module name to load it from some relative path from my main C++ program?

**test.py code**

```
n = 10
d = {1:5,2:10}
```

**test.cc code**

```
#include <Python.h>   
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void c_python_intf(long long int i1,const char* s1,long long int i2)
{
   PyObject *mymod = NULL;
   PyObject *testmod = NULL;
   PyObject *py_attr_num = NULL;
   PyObject *python_func,*args,*myResult,*myData,*myString,*myNum;
   const char* py_var;
   long long int myData_updated;
   string myString_updated;
   long long int myNum_updated;
   cout << "input to c function is " << i1 << "\t\t" << s1 << "\t\t" << i2 << endl ;
   PyGILState_STATE gstate;
   gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();  
   string st = "/projects/name/dir/subdir";
   char *path;
   path = st.c_str();
   PySys_SetPath(path);
   // testmod = PyImport_ImportModule(".projects.name.dir.subdir.py_module");
   // testmod = PyImport_ImportModule("/projects/name/dir/subdir/py_module");
   testmod = PyImport_ImportModule("py_module");
   py_attr_num = PyObject_GetAttrString(testmod, "n");
   PyObject_Print(py_attr_num,stdout,0);
   cout << stdout << endl;
   py_attr_num = PyObject_GetAttrString(testmod, "d");
   PyObject_Print(py_attr_num,stdout,0);
   cout << stdout << endl;  
 }

 static PyMethodDef myModule_methods[] = { 
       {NULL, NULL} 
 };

 extern "C" { 
     /* * Python calls this to let us initialize our module */ 
   void initpython_sim(void) { 
           (void) Py_InitModule("python_sim", myModule_methods); 
   }
 }

 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
    string mod_name;
    cout << "###########################################" << endl;
    cout << "Running C++ code" << endl;
    cout << "###########################################" << endl;

    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    Py_Initialize();
    initpython_sim();
    const char* input_string = "00110100000010100100001000000000";
    c_python_intf(100000000000LL,input_string,5000000000LL);
    //Py_Main(argc, argv);
    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
 }
```

**Note** :- Code has been updated to remove redundant code which is not blocking the issue specified here. Hence please ignore input arguments to c_python_intf function.

The problem is since the python module and C++ program is not in the same directory its not able to load the python module. By copying the python module into the same directory where C++ program is written, it works.

**How to tackle with this problem if python module and C++ program is not in the same directory?**

Comment: Insufficient info. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Okay, here's the code. Now, where does the error happen (and what error)? Segmentation fault at `py_attr_num = PyObject_GetAttrString(...)`? If that's the case, the import must be failing, and you're not checking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below code works for me,

**in Linux use:**

```
setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 1);
```

**In Windows:**

```
_putenv_s("PYTHONPATH", ".");
```

you can replace your address in instead of ".", which illustrate the active path

Answer (score 1):

[`PyImport_ImportModule`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/import.html?highlight=pyimport_importmodule#c.PyImport_ImportModule) is a direct counterpart to `import` and accepts the *name* of the module rather than file path. If the module to load is not on `sys.path`, you need to add the corresponding `sys.path` entry.